# Select portions of one column and paste as new column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file in the following format:

```
# Comment 
# Comment 
# Comment
@ Title
@ Label 
@ Label
1       2
2       5
3       7
&
1       7
2       4
3       9
&
```

So the first column repeats itself, and the second column changes. They're separated by a "&" in the first column and an empty space in the second column. There might be 1000s of such sections. I'd like to cut the portion of the second column and paste it as a new column, so in this case:

```
# Comment 
# Comment 
# Comment
@ Title
@ Label 
@ Label
1     2     7
2     5     4
3     7     9
```

Then I could graph all the columns more easily. I also don't care about the first lines, in case is easier to just remove them or leave them there, doesn't matter much.

Comment: Would a 3rd section of two columns be handled in the same way, i.e. that the second column is added as a 4th new column?

Comment: Correct. If the output has n sections in 2 columns, I'd like to convert that into n columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run it:

```
cat << EOF | awk '
$1 == "#" || $1 == "@" { print; next }
$1 != "&" { result[$1] = (result[$1] ? result[$1] : $1) "\t" $2 }
END { for (i in result) print result[i] }
'
# Comment 
# Comment 
# Comment
@ Title
@ Label 
@ Label
1       2
2       5
3       7
&
1       7
2       4
3       9
&
EOF
```

Or you can use the file **filename** with input data. In this case run:

```
awk '
$1 == "#" || $1 == "@" { print; next }
$1 != "&" { result[$1] = (result[$1] ? result[$1] : $1) "\t" $2 }
END { for (i in result) print result[i] }
' filename
```

In both cases you'll get the result:

```
# Comment 
# Comment 
# Comment
@ Title
@ Label 
@ Label
1   2   7
2   5   4
3   7   9
```

It will work with any number of columns.

Comment: it works, thank you! For some reason however the output is out of order, any way to fix this? It's not a big problem since I can fix it in my spreadsheet, but it would help with my worflow. If it matters the numbers in each column can be very large and not only single digits.

Comment: @egil137, The easiest way to sort output is to add  `| sort -n` after awk execution. It will look `' | sort -n` in the first example and `' filename | sort -n` in the second one.